# Is there a way to access phone gallery in reactjs application?

Tags: reactjs, camera, react-redux, gallery, progressive-web-apps

Hi I am developing a ReactJS application which eventually I will have to convert into PWA application. My confusion is whether we have any reactJS plugins which can help me solve this problem. For the web, it is easy using file dialogs, selectors, but if we want to open the same thing on device (android, iOS) is there any way or logic?